# Parsing data with Pattern in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I get a response from server, which seems like:

```
<span class="name_cards">
<a href="LINK">NAME</a>     <img alt="" src="IMAGE" />
</span>
<table class="tbl_card">
<tr>
        <th colspan="2">
            BALANCE <span class="CURRENCY">TEXT</span>
        </th>
</tr>
</table>

<span class="name_cards">
<a href="LINK 2">TEXT 2</a></span>
<table class="tbl_card">
<tr>
        <th colspan="2">
            BALANCE 2 <span class="CURRENCY">TEXT</span>
        </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to create a regular expression to parse? 
I tried

```
<span class="name_cards">((.|\n)*?)<\x2ftable>
```

on http://regexr.com/ and it worked, but when i put it in Android Studio, Matcher showed no matches.

Comment: What about [`"(?s)<span class=\"name_cards\">(.*?)</table>"`](http://fiddle.re/1ux596)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java Strings a `\` needs to be escaped so try replacing `\x2` with `\x2`

You will also have to escape the `"` to be `\"` and the `\n`
(I should have read the regex more carefully the first time)

Basically you have to double all the `\` in your Strings in Java as the `\` tells the compiler do treat the next character as a control code.

Also android studio should tell you your regex is wrong, at least IntelliJ does then you do `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("regex");`

Comment: <span class=\"name_cards\">((.|\\n)*?)<\\x2ftable> also showed no matches :(

Comment: regexplanet also shows no matches.  I don't think your input string (as detailed in the question) matches what you have told you regex.

Comment: regexplanet.com will also turn your regex into a valid have string, its my preferred regex site.

Comment: passing it through rubular (a ruby regex) gets you some matches.  So perhaps you are providing some non-java regex options in there.

Comment: try ```Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<span class=\"name_cards\">((.|\\n)*?)<\\x2ftable>", Pattern.UNIX_LINES);```